# ImportError: No module named appengine.api -windows 10,local env, python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, windows-10, gcloud

I want to use google appengine.api in local machine. i have installed google cloud SDK and started it ,the authentication is successful . I have executed  `$dev_appserver.py app.yaml` at the project path which has started a google app engine server at localhost:8000 .

when i want to execute the program it gives an error message " ImportError: No module named appengine.api "

I appreciate your help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried executing the project in local in pycharm, so i got the above error(google.appengine.api error). Basically it has to be executed on a server.The server can be started using your terminal.

1) Go to the project path(root folder of all files in the project where the app.yaml file is located,eg: appengine)
2) start the server using $ dev_appserver.py app.yaml. It starts server at localhost port 8000 as the default one.
3) In the server start depends on the handler and its path specified (like '/' or '/testjob') try localhost:8000/ or localhost:8000/testjob
4) All the logs written in the program will be shown in the terminal. For logs try using 'logging' module , make sure to mention the logging level else basic level logs are not shown

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is it is an error in the code you are deploying. Are you able to get the Hello World to work?:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/quickstart#download_the_hello_world_app

Comment: when i executed $dev_appserver.py app.yaml at the project path, At localhost:8080 'Hello, World' is printed.  Similarly i could see my program content at localhost:8080 but when i try to debug it or print the output statements while executing the program using 'python programName.py' i could see errors. i want to debug the program to make modifications in it .

Comment: You may be able to use the `--persist_logs` flag: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/logs/#the_development_server_and_logs_api

Comment: Thank you Jonace, yes --persist_logs flag would work.